# How to sort multiple associated arrays in C language？

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort multiple associated arrays. One of the arrays is sorted as key and the rest of the arrays are sorted as value following the movement of the key.
e.g.:

```
int a[4] = {4, 3, 1, 2};
float b[4] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
```

Now I take the a[] array as the key to sort these two arrays, and the result after sorting should be:

```
int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
float b[4] = {3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0};
```

I use C language to accomplish this problem because I wanted to know what would be a better algorithm to solve this. The problem can be easily solved in C++ using a std::map. But is the performance of map the best? If so, does that mean that I implement a temporary map in C and then complete an out-place sort is the best solution?

It is true that putting different values in a structure to sort them is a good way. However, what is not clear to me is whether the memory move with extra values is the most efficient way. Especially  if the elements of the second array are some kind of complex structure, it will use a very large number of bytes. Another idea is to sort the keys and then use some strategy to minimize the copy of the values. @daro provides an implementation, but it seems to change the complexity from O(nlogn) for sorting to O(n^2).

I hope some programmers who know about this problem will give me more information and details. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you need two different arrays? I'd put both values in a struct and sort an array of that.

Comment: It is true that putting different values in a structure to sort them is a good way. However, what is not clear to me is whether the memory move with extra values is the most efficient way. Especially if the elements of the second array are some kind of complex structure, it will use a very large number of bytes. Another idea is to sort the keys and then use some strategy to minimize the copy of the values. @Daro provides an implementation, but it seems to change the complexity from O(nlogn) for sorting to O(n^2).

Comment: Possibly related: [Arrange one array and other array do the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920823/arrange-one-array-and-other-array-do-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help. Read the code carefully so You understand it.

```
void sort(int *key, float *data, int len)
{
    int *key_backup = (int*) malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(key_backup, key, len * sizeof(int));
    
    // Here, insert sorting 'key' somehow
    
    unsigned char *exclude1 = (unsigned char*) malloc(len * sizeof(unsigned char));
    unsigned char *exclude2 = (unsigned char*) malloc(len * sizeof(unsigned char));
    
    memset(exclude1, 0, len * sizeof(unsigned char));
    memset(exclude2, 0, len * sizeof(unsigned char));
    
    float *new_data = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * len)
    
    for(int aa = 0; aa < len; aa++)
    {
        if(exclude1[aa])
        continue;
        
        for(int bb = 0; bb < len; bb++)
        {
            if(exclude2[bb])
            continue;
            
            if(key_backup[aa] == key[bb])
            {
                exclude1[aa] = 1;
                exclude2[bb] = 1;
                
                new_data[bb] = data[aa];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    free(key_backup);
    free(exclude1);
    free(exclude2);

    memcpy(data, new_data);
    free(new_data);
}
```

Comment: code edited. Check again

Comment: "The comment" is a bit unclear, starting with non-dictionary word *someware*. How about `// Here, insert sorting 'key' somehow`? I suggest to use const pointers. You do not document the return value to be allocated, inviting a memory leak. You leak memory from the exclude1/2 pointers, which from C99 should be bool*.

Comment: I think for `exclude1` to be any use, you need to set `exclude1[bb]`, not `exclude1[aa]`.

Comment: I think the entire handling of duplicate keys needs explanation, if not correction. (As one test, use `b` from the question, `a[] = {1, 1, 1, 1}`)

Comment: From [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74077984/2): *Analysis of scenario a[] = {1, 1, 1, 1}: …
    if(key_backup[0] == key[1]) returns 'true'

    exclude1[1] and exclude2[1] is set* if only! But what really gets set is `exclude1[aa]` which is `exclude1[0]`.